# Make an external link to an iFrame in a webpage

Tags: php, iframe, hyperlink, external

I have a page with an iFrame in it. I want to be able to send links to people, that will open a page within that iFrame on my page.

The main (parent) page is called `results.html`
The iFrame has the id "searchresults"

The page that I wan people to be able to open within that iFrame is `results.php`, but it would have a number of parameters in it (for example `results.php?id=5`)

**How would I construct the link to send to people?**

For example, would it be `/results.html?target="searchresults";?results.php?id=5`

I simply can't work it out!

Comment: Is results.html a page processed by server? (eg: php, jsp or aspx)?

Comment: No, @vivek - but it could be if needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What stops you from simply loading the iFrame and the main frame with the same GET parameters?

Or the place where you add iFrame, simply add the GET parameters of the main page also to the iFrame and then check for their presence in the iFrame code?

For example, I have a page:

```
index.php
```

In this page I have an iFrame with an URL:

```
<iframe src="search.php"></iframe>
```

If I make a search, then the main page would change:

```
index.php?search=test
```

Now when I am generating the iFrame URL, I check if that GET parameter exists, if it exists then I append it to iFrame URL:

```
<iframe src="search.php?search=test"></iframe>
```

Comment: This sounds interesting - how would I implement this? Would you be able to pen a little code for it? It sounds very good @kristovaher